# Convert txt file to CSV? - On a Linux Server

Tags: linux, bash, csv, converters, wget

I want to set up a scheduled task on my website which is hosted on a linux server. This task should download [this txt](http://www.cdkeys.com/feeds/cdkeys_affiliate_feed_eur.txt) file and convert it to CSV.

You can see that the txt file looks like a CSV file. But it is just written in txt.. So, I have to convert it...

I tried it local on my Mac and renamed it. It works. But If I say `wget` and save the txt file as csv file, I get a destroyed file.

So, which way is the best way to do that?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: A csv file is just a text file...

Comment: But if I open it in Excel after saved it as CSV with `wget`- It is destroyed...

Comment: What do you mean it gets destroyed, excel doesn't destroy files it can't open...

Comment: Here you can have a look: http://imgur.com/5tJflQ1

Comment: And it looks okay if you don't open it in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a CSV file but a TSV file, you can download and convert it like so:

```
curl -s https://www.cdkeys.com/feeds/cdkeys_affiliate_feed_eur.txt | tr "\t" "," > output.csv
```

Or if you want the format that excel likes by default, iirc you need to use a semicolon instead of a comma (so substitute the `","` with a `";"`)

Comment: You can use tab as a separator in excel